# How to change the order of albums in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Has anyone figured out how to change the order of albums with new Facebook layout which was rolled out in 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of May 24, 2015, it has been reported that going through the following link will allow changing the order of albums easily:

```
https://www.facebook.com/media/albums/?id=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The solution was posted on Facebook [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151501688224322), and most users, including myself, found that it is working.